# Difference in integers in an array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I was working on a problem and got stuck. Here is the problem.

You are walking along a hiking trail. On this hiking trail, there is elevation marker at every kilometer. The elevation information is represented in an array of integers. For example, if the elevation array is [100, 50, 20, 30, 50, 40], that means at kilometer 0, the elevation is 100 meters; at kilometer 1, the elevation is 50 meters; at kilometer 2, the elevation is 20 meters; at kilometer 3, the elevation is 30 meters; at kilometer 4, the elevation is 50 meters; at kilometer 5, the elevation is 40 meters.

b) Write a method called longestUphill that returns the elevation change in meters of the longest uphill section. In the example above, the method should return 30 because the longest uphill section is from kilometer 2 with 20 meters to kilometer 4 with 50 meters. The elevation change is 50 - 20 = 30 meters.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public int longestUphill(int[] elevation)
{
    int end,longest=0;
    for(int i=0;i<elevation.length-1;i++){
    end = i+1;
    while(elevation[end]-elevation[i]>=0){
        end++;
    }
    if(elevation[end]-elevation[i]>longest) longest = elevation[end]-elevation[i];
}
return longest;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you stuck?  Tell us what your conceptual problem is with your code.

Comment: No idea...what you want

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you throw away what you have written (!) and start again.

Hint: break the problem down into two parts:

1. Find the longest uphill section.  Hint: an uphill section is one where `elevation[i - 1] < elevation[i]` for all `i` in the section.
2. Find the elevation change in a given section.  Hint: if you know a section is all uphill, then there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: could you share it? I'm kinda new to Java :)

Comment: No.  This is your homework.  The idea is that you >>learn<< by writing the code yourself.  If you don't do your own howmework, you are always going to be "new to Java".

Comment: @StephenC you are right...

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic iterate array and compare and save result...

1. Iterate array and compare current element with the next element
2. if next element have higher value add difference in result.
3. else logic for compare the results you have and save the higher value.
   3.1 compare result value with saved value if saved value.
   3.2 if result is higher replace save with result..
4. return saved value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer... I think this is what you're lookin' for! XD

```
    public static int longestUphill(int[] elevation){
    int longest=0;
    for(int i=0;i<elevation.length-1;i++){
        if(elevation[i]<elevation[i+1]){
            int temp= elevation[i+1]-elevation[i];
            for(int j=i+1;j<elevation.length-1;j++){
                if(elevation[j]<elevation[j+1]){
                    temp += elevation[j+1]-elevation[j];
                }
                else{
                    if(longest<temp)
                        longest= temp;
                    i=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

Well... the idea is to iterate through the elevation array and start incrementing the longest variable while the actual value is lower than the next one. If the next one is lower than actual (another hole, uphill)  update the i with j value so we don't analyze again in main loop what was previously analyzed by j's loop.

Comment: could you add an explanation please?

Comment: I have just edited the answer.... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (int i=0;i<elevation.length-1;i++){

           if(elevation[i] < elevation[i+1]){

               temp += (elevation[i+1] - elevation[i]);

           }
```

it basically goes this way:
is the current element < than the next one? if so then sum up the difference  between them and save it into temp var, which is only a temporary variable.

```
else {
      if(result<temp)
            result = temp;
            temp = 0;
    }
```

if the first condition aint met then we compare result against temp which initial value is 0 so if temp > result we save it into result and reset temp variable to 0.

```
return (result<temp)?temp:result;
```

Finally we return the highest uphill comparing the actual result against temp which will set the value to return to the biggest of them.

```
  public static int[] arr={100,50,20,30,50,40};

   public static int longestUphill(int[] elevation){
        int temp=0,result=0;

        for (int i=0;i<elevation.length-1;i++){

           if(elevation[i] < elevation[i+1]){

               temp += (elevation[i+1] - elevation[i]);

           }
           else {
              if(result<temp)
                  result = temp;
              temp = 0;
           }

        }

        return (result<temp)?temp:result;
   }
```